# Copying a Table in MySQL and including the Primary Key

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an ancient code snippet I use for copying tables in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (select * from old_table);
```

This works great, with one exception.  It doesn't copy the primary key or other table indexes.

Is there any way to copy a table in MySQL AND include the indexes/primary key??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theres one of two ways. To see how a table is built you can use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE old_table
```

You could also (I think you'll have to test it), run this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Comment: Tested the `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE` syntax on 5.1.36. Indexes are copied but not foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

but it does not provide duplicating data.